# Why do I get False when using issubclass in this way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Structure:

```
package/
    m1.py
    m2.py
```

**`m1.py`:**

```
class A:
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from m2 import B

    print(issubclass(B, A))
```

**`m2.py`:**

```
from m1 import A


class B(A):
    pass
```

I don't now why I get false while I think it's obviously true when I run m1.py. My python version is python3.5.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wellcome to the world of modules and namespaces!

Here is what happens:

In module m2, you import A from module m1. So you create a class `m2.A` as a reference to class `m1.A`. It happens to have the same definition as `__main__.A`, but they are different objects, because the main module is named `__main__` and not `m1`. Then in module `__main__` you create a class `__main__.B` as a reference to class `m2.B`

To better understand what happens here, I have added some code to m1:

```
...
print(issubclass(B, A))

import m1
import m2
print(A == m1.A, m1.A == m2.A)
print(B == m2.B)
print(issubclass(B, m2.A), issubclass(B, m1.A))
```

The output is:

```
False
False True
True
True True
```

Proving that B is indeed a subclass of `m1.A` but not of `__main__.A`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to derive class `A` from `object` to get `issubclass` do its job:

[isinstance() and issubclass() behavior differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107313/isinstance-and-issubclass-behavior-differently)

```
class A(object): ...
```

Here an example of python cli:

```
>>> class A(object): pass
>>> class B(A): pass
>>> issubclass(B,A)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You create 2 class objects, derived from the same class. That is: the class code is executed twice and thus results in 2 objects. And those are not the same. Example: see the output of the `print` statements below

```
# m2.py
from m1 import A

class B(A):
    pass

print(A)

# m1.py
class A:
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from m2 import B
    print(A)
    print(issubclass(B, A))

# Output
#<class 'm1.A'>
#<class '__main__.A'>
#False
```

Also: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11461574/5488275) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

IN m1.py you are providing class A and in m2.py you are importing class of A. Even though it is imported from m1.py it is not the same object.  You never actually import the exact object you just import the code and a sperate object is created.  So instead of importing class A you just had two separate class A() code blocks would you expect them to be a subclass of each other just because they have the same name.  You are not checking if the class has the same name you are checking if the class is an subclass of an actual class object (not just the text of the name).

It would be no different than importing class A from a 3rd completely different module because you are just importing code not objects.